# How to link/connect Firebase and Google App Engine for image resizing

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase and I'm trying to leverage the image resizing service that AppEngine has with  `get_serving_url()`. https://medium.com/google-cloud/uploading-resizing-and-serving-images-with-google-cloud-platform-ca9631a2c556.

I'm confused about how to go about linking my google app engine image resizing service to my firebase cloud storage instance.

I see this quote in the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration

> The Firebase SDKs for Cloud Storage use the Google App Engine default
>   bucket, which means that if you build an App Engine app, you can use
>   the built in App Engine APIs to share data between Firebase and App
>   Engine. This is useful for performing audio encoding, video
>   transcoding, and image transformations, as well as other computation
>   intensive background processing.

How can I point to this `Google App Engine default bucket`?  I don't see it in the google app engine dashboard interface anywhere.

I've already set up a firebase project and I then created an app engine project - but I don't see any way to point my app engine to the `default bucket` that firebase created.  Is that based on some sort of account id?  Where in the admin interface or tools can I set up that linkage so that the files I'm uploading to the firebase default storage bucket are available to be resized by the app engine image server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing Firebase project, then the corresponding Google Cloud project is created for you automatically.

Just go to Google Cloud console (https://console.cloud.google.com) and there you'll be able to select the project with the same name (as your Firebase project's). If you deploy your GAE app to that project then it should be able to access your data.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible to link existing firebase projects with an existing google cloud platform (GCP) / app engine project.

- First create the GCP app engine project
- Then, on firebase, go to Add Project -> Open the "Project name" drop-down and select the existing GCP project.

The firebase project ID will then be the same as the GCP project ID, the GCP default bucket gs://<project_id>.appspot.com is the default firebase storage bucket, and you can select additional GCP buckets on the firebase storage page.